# Как сверить элементы двух массивов?

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер, каким образом можно сверить элементы двух массивов в JavaScript?

Имеем один массив, полностью набитый ссылками. Допустим:

```
var one=['mail.ru','google.com','yandex.ru','rambler.ru'];
```

И другой, 'динамический' массив с минимум 1-м, максимум 3-мя елементами, в зависимости от ситуации.. Тоже содержит ссылки.

```
var two=['google.com','rambler.ru'];  //пример с 2-мя елементами
```

Нужно както проверить совпадают ли элементы второго массива с первым, и если да (у меня в примере совпало 2 элемента) - дать знать какие именно, например index'ы элементов в 1м массиве.

Пытался что-то через обычный for и if сделать, но запутался =\

Comment: Минуснул, есть задание, но нет признаков самостоятельных попыток решения. Тривиальное задание, кстати.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var idx=0;
for (var i=0;i<two.length;i++)
{
  idx=one.indexOf(two[i]);
  if (idx>=0) alert(idx);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

вариант с использованием [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/):

```
_.each(['mail.ru','google.com','yandex.ru','rambler.ru'], function(url, idx){
    if(_.include(['google.com','rambler.ru'], url)){
        alert(idx);
    }  
});
// или
_.intersection(['mail.ru','google.com','yandex.ru','rambler.ru'], ['google.com','rambler.ru']); 
// вернёт пересечение элементов массивов, т.е.
['google.com','rambler.ru']
```

Comment: Мало jQuery :-)

Comment: Все же для таких задач базового JS вполне достаточно, ИМХО